# Powers of Ideals Clarification

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am having a hard time wrapping my mind around powers of ideals. For example, in Dummit and Foote it is states (without explanation) that $$\langle x \rangle + \langle x,y \rangle^2 = \langle x, y^2 \rangle$$

I've been attempting to prove this to myself using the fact that $\langle x, y \rangle \cdot \langle x,y \rangle = \{ \sum_{i=1}^m c_i d_i : c_i \in \langle x ,y \rangle, d_i \in \langle x, y \rangle \}$.

Unfortunately, I've been making a mess of it and I don't think my attempt will be of much use for other readers (why I am not typing it out).

How do you cleanly show the above equality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Show that $\langle x, y \rangle^2 = \langle x^2, xy, y^2 \rangle$.  Or show more generally that
$$
\langle f_1, \ldots, f_m \rangle \langle g_1, \ldots, g_n \rangle = \langle f_i g_j : 1 \leq i \leq m, 1 \leq j \leq n \rangle \, .
$$

To get you started, recall that an element of $\langle x, y \rangle$ looks like $xf(x,y) + yg(x,y)$ for some $f,g \in F[x,y]$.  What happens if you multiply two elements of this form?

Once you have $\langle x, y \rangle^2 = \langle x^2, xy, y^2 \rangle$, do you see why
$$
\langle x \rangle + \langle x^2, xy, y^2 \rangle = \langle x, y^2 \rangle \ ?
$$